# Pundit policy_scope with Grape api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, grape-api, pundit

I am building API endpoints with `Grape`.

I have below `scope`:

```
class JourneyPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def create?
    user && user.identt_id == record
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope.where(user_id: user.id).latest
    end
  end
end
```

And now, I want to use this `policy_scope` in my grape resource, we can use `policy_scope(Journey)` in rails controller, but I can't make it working with grape endpoint:

```
class Journeys < Grape::API
  resources :journeys do
    get do
      @journeys = policy_scope(Journey)
      present @journeys, with: Entities::Journey
    end
  end
end
```

This is not working, and I am getting `NoMethodError` for `policy_scope`.

I would like to use that grape policy and any help would be appreciated :)

**NOTE:**

I have below code which is working in grape endpoint to authorize resources like:

```
error!("Unauthorized Access!", 401) unless JourneyPolicy.new(journey, uid).create?
```

Thanks

Comment: I've never used Rails but I guess that the method policy_scope() exists only in Rails. I'm not sure but I believe you should use JourneyPolicy.new(journey, uid).create? instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but I created a helper method in `grape` manually named `policy_scope` like:

```
  def policy_scope(user, scope)
    policy = "#{scope}Policy::Scope".constantize
    policy.new(user, scope).resolve
  end
```

Now, I can call policy_scope helper from my grape resources like:

```
policy_scope(current_user, Journey)
```

and it is working for me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`policy_scope` in Rails application using Pundit comes from `Pundit::Authorization` module. As long as your Grape API controller has `current_user` method you should be able to simply `include Pundit::Authorization` into your base Grape API controller.

Alternatively you can also look up scopes [the "manual" way](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#manually-retrieving-policies-and-scopes):

```rb
Pundit.policy_scope!(current_user, Journey)
```